# after pull swiperefreshlayout , recyclerview loadmore wont work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

After I pulled the SwipeRefreshLayout on my app, the recyclerview loadmore function wont work anymore.

The recyclerView is at the fragment of the viewpager, and the viewpager is on the one of the fragment which hold by viewpager at activity.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: this issue fixed